# More elegant way to check for an event/trigger periodically?

Tags: python, multithreading, event-handling, timeout, raspberry-pi

I have a passive infrared sensor and I wanted to turn off and on my display based on motion. E.g. if there is no motion for 5 minutes, then the display should turn off to save power. However if there is motion don't turn off the display, or turn it back on. (Don't ask why isn't a screensaver good for this. The device I'm making won't have any keyboard or mouse. It only will be a standalone display.)

My idea was to create two threads, a producer, and a consumer. The producer thread (the PIR sensor) puts a message into a queue, which the consumer (which controls the display) reads. This way I can send signals from one to another.

I have a fully functional code below (with some explanation), which completes the previously described. My question is that is there some way to achieve this in a more elegant way? What do you think of my approach, is it okay, is it hackish?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Queue
from threading import Thread
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
import os
import sys

class PIRSensor:

    # PIR sensor's states
    current_state = 0
    previous_state = 0

    def __init__(self, pir_pin, timeout):
        # PIR GPIO pin
        self.pir_pin = pir_pin
        # Timeout between motion detections
        self.timeout = timeout

    def setup(self):
        gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
        gpio.setup(self.pir_pin, gpio.IN)
        # Wait for the PIR sensor to settle
        # (loop until PIR output is 0)
        while gpio.input(self.pir_pin) == 1:
            self.current_state = 0

    def report_motion(self, queue):
        try:
            self.setup()

            while True:
                self.current_state = gpio.input(self.pir_pin)

                if self.current_state == 1 and self.previous_state == 0:
                    # PIR sensor is triggered
                    queue.put(True)
                    # Record previous state
                    self.previous_state = 1
                elif self.current_state == 1 and self.previous_state == 1:
                    # Feed the queue since there is still motion
                    queue.put(True)
                elif self.current_state == 0 and self.previous_state == 1:
                    # PIR sensor has returned to ready state
                    self.previous_state = 0

                time.sleep(self.timeout)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise

class DisplayControl:

    # Display's status
    display_on = True

    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = timeout

    def turn_off(self):
        # Turn off the display
        if self.display_on:
            os.system("/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o > /dev/null 2>&1")
            self.display_on = False

    def turn_on(self):
        # Turn on the display
        if not self.display_on:
            os.system("{ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p && chvt 9 && chvt 7 ; } > /dev/null 2>&1")
            self.display_on = True

    def check_motion(self, queue):
        try:
            while True:
                try:
                    motion = queue.get(True, self.timeout)

                    if motion:
                        self.turn_on()
                except Queue.Empty:
                        self.turn_off()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        pir_sensor = PIRSensor(7, 0.25)
        display_control = DisplayControl(300)
        queue = Queue.Queue()

        producer = Thread(target=pir_sensor.report_motion, args=(queue,))
        consumer = Thread(target=display_control.check_motion, args=(queue,))

        producer.daemon = True
        consumer.daemon = True

        producer.start()
        consumer.start()

        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        display_control.turn_on()
        # Reset GPIO settings
        gpio.cleanup()
        sys.exit(0)
```

The producer thread runs a function (`report_motion`) of a `PIRSensor` class instance. The PIRSensor class reads the state of a passive infrared sensor four times per second, and whenever it senses motion puts a message into a queue.

The consumer thread runs a function of (`check_motion`) of a `DisplayControl` class instance. It reads the previously mentioned queue in blocking mode with a given timeout. The following can happen:

- If the display is on and there is no message in the queue for a given
  time, aka the timeout expires, the consumer thread will power off the
  display.
- If the display is off and a message comes, the thread will
  power on the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a good solution. The reason being that you have separated the concerns for the different classes. One class handles the PIR sensor. One handles the display. You glue them together by a queue today, that's one approach.

By doing this you can easily test the different classes.

To extend this (read make it extendable) you might introduce a  controller. The controller gets events (e.g. from the queue) and acts on the events (e.g. tell the Display Controller to turn off the display). The controller knows about the sensor, and knows about the display. But the sensor should not know about the display or vice versa. (this is very similar to MVC where in this case the data is the model (sensor), the display is the view and the controller sits in between.

This approach makes the design testable, extendable, maintainable. And by that you are not hackish, you are writing real code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea is good. The only question I have about your implementation is why have both the consumer and producer in child threads? You could just keep the consumer in the main thread, and then there'd be no need to have this meaningless loop in your main thread.

```
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

which is just wasting CPU cycles. Instead you could just call `display_motion.check_motion(queue)` directly.